# Creating Python timer for Nokia 5800

Tags: python, mobile, nokia

I've been asked to write a microsecond timer for nokia 5800. I have googled it but still haven't made any headway. 
Firstly, i don't know jack about programming nokia devices and mobiles in general. Please could someone point me in the right directions. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you have been asked to do the job if you know nothing about it?

[read this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_create_a_timer)